# Merge N arrays to 1 single array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to merge 4 arrays into 1 single array using javascript and throws error.

```
var dif1 = {name: 'sree', age:'33'};
var dif2 = {name: 'kavitha', age:'34'};
var dif3 = {name: 'darshan', gender:'Male'};
var dif4 = {name: 'suchi', gender:'Female'};
```

I want results like below

```
{
{name: 'sree', age:'33'},
{name: 'kavitha', age:'34'},
{name: 'darshan', gender:'Male'},
{name: 'suchi', gender:'Female'}
}
```

I have tried with concat method and it's throwing an error saying **.concat** is not a function.

Comment: Your expected output is not an array (That is like a javascript set), do you want to store objects in a single array or not?

Comment: are you here referring for objects or arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Those are 4 objects and you are trying to put objects in an object without a key value pair, and if you want to make a array of them then use below code. Try to run the snippet to see the result.

```js
var dif1 = {name: 'sree', age:'33'};
var dif2 = {name: 'kavitha', age:'34'};
var dif3 = {name: 'darshan', gender:'Male'};
var dif4 = {name: 'suchi', gender:'Female'};

let arr = []

arr.push(dif1, dif2, dif3, dif4)
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing here are not *arrays* but these are *objects*. Object is a structure that has a key and a value. You might be confused because in some languages, objects are called *associative arrays*.

You can merge the four objects into one array using the `concat()` method or the spread operator.

```js
// Method 1: Using concat()
var mergedArray = [].concat(dif1, dif2, dif3, dif4);
console.log(mergedArray);

// Method 2: Using the spread operator
var mergedArray = [...dif1, ...dif2, ...dif3, ...dif4];
console.log(mergedArray);
```

Both will return the same value

```js
[
  { name: 'sree', age: '33' },
  { name: 'kavitha', age: '34' },
  { name: 'darshan', gender: 'Male' },
  { name: 'suchi', gender: 'Female' }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the objects: dif1, dif2, dif3, dif4, are hardcoded you could create an array of objects to begin with:

```js
const obj_array = [
  {name: 'sree', age:'33'},
  {name: 'kavitha', age:'34'},
  {name: 'darshan', gender:'Male'},
  {name: 'suchi', gender:'Female'}
]
```

and if you want to add new objects to the array later:

```js
obj_array.push({ name: 'a', gender: 'b' })
```

Here are all the methods that are available besides `push` on an array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_methods

Answer (score 0):

In terms of merging multiple objects into a single object, it can be done using two methods.

**1st method:**

```
var dif1 = {name: 'sree', age:'33'};
var dif2 = {name: 'kavitha', age:'34'};
var dif3 = {name: 'darshan', gender:'Male'};
var dif4 = {name: 'suchi', gender:'Female'};

var obj = {...diff1, ...dif2 ,...dif3 ,...dif4};
```

**2nd method:**

```
let newObj = Object.assign({}, diff1, dif2 , dif3, dif4);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
{name: 'sree', age:'33'},
{name: 'kavitha', age:'34'},
{name: 'darshan', gender:'Male'},
{name: 'suchi', gender:'Female'}
}
```

is not an object, javascript objects are key:value structred.
if you want to merge into one object, you should add keys for each array.
if you want to merge into one array, you should make the {} into  [] .